# How can I read content file, do some instructions, and then copy out all the interesting content to another file line by line?

Tags: perl, file-io

File 1 :

```
1. "a:1 b c:10 d e f g:2 a:1 a:1 a:1"
2. "h i l m"
3. "e:1 b"
4. "f:2 e:5 a"
```

File 2 should be

```
1. "a:1 c:10 g:2"
2. "f:2 e:5"
```

So I would like to:

1. save just one sample in case of repeated elements (for ex. line 1 "a:1"),
2. check if the line includes the element I'd like to save (so it must be for ex. "a:1" and not just "a")
3. if there's just one interesting element (line 3) I'll not evaluate the line.

I've tried to put the file content into an array inside a while cycle but when I printed Out my content it was all printed in line 1.

this is my attempt:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);

$in = "in.txt";
$out = "out.txt";

open (IN, "<", $in);
open (OUT, ">", $out);

while(defined ( $l = <IN>)){
    @a = split (/\s/, $l);
    @c= uniq(@a);
    for ($i = 0; $i < @c; $i++){
        if ($c[$i] =~ /.*:-?\d\.\d+/) {
            print OUT $c[$i];   
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you have made an attempt already, you should add it to your question.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question exactly, but I think this is half of what you wanted: cat file1 | perl -lne 'my $count += () = $_ =~ /\w:\d/g; print if $count > 1;'
"a:1 b c:10 d e f g:2 a:1 a:1 a:1"
"f:2 e:5 a"

Comment: the problem is that I've an obligation of confidentiality for data. For this reason I've just write an example of my data.

Comment: done..  @fin this is something I should write in the CLI?

Comment: Have to? No. This will work, though: cat file1 | tr -d '"' | perl -ne 'my %res; for (split /\s/, $_) { $res{$_}++ if /\w+:\d+/ }; if (scalar keys %res > 1) { print "$_ " for keys %res; print "\n" };' -- I did get rid of the quotes, but it's not hard to put them back if you need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a bit of fun playing with this problem.

It may not help you that much as it is a little tricky to read, but this is what I ended up with:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);
$in = "in.txt";
$out = "out.txt";

open (IN, "<", $in);
open (OUT, ">", $out);

foreach (<IN>) {
   @result =  map /.\:\d*/ ? $_ : (), uniq ( split ) ;
   print OUT join(" ", @result) . "\n" unless ($#result < 1);
}
```

Output:

```
a:1 c:10 g:2
f:2 e:5
```

Here is a version that doesn't use uniq and uses the -n option to handle the while loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n
my %seen;
@result =  map /.\:\d*/ ? $_ : (), grep {! $seen{$_}++ } ( split ) ;
print join(" ", @result) . "\n" unless ($#result < 1);
```

Output:

```
./myscript.pl in.txt
a:1 c:10 g:2
f:2 e:5
```

I just noticed its not supposed to print if there is only one result.
That's easy to fix by changing the $#result test.

Comment: Oops, forgot to include the use statement.

Comment: I have 2 questions: 1. why did you use a foreach and not a while cycle and "map /.\:\d*/ ? $_ : (), uniq ( split ) ;" can you explain to me the syntax please?

Comment: "@names = qw(Franz, François, Stef, Lorette);
my @invited = map { $_ =~ /^F/ ? ($_ => 1) : () } @names;
print "@invited\n" " ....  I found it. So I think it is just the same syntax. However is there a reason why there is ": () " ?

Comment: The '? $_ : ()' part is just to handle the case where nothing matches.  Otherwise the join puts in more than one space.

Comment: I usually always use foreach on lists.  It's nice an simple.

Answer (score 3):

This will do what you ask.

It isn't clear whether the line numbers and quotation marks are part of your data, but I have written it so that it doesn't matter either way

The program expects the path to the input file as a parameter on the command line

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
  my %seen;
  my @wanted = grep { /:/ and not $seen{$_}++ } /[^\s"]+/g;
  print "@wanted\n" if @wanted > 1;
}
```

**output**

```
a:1 c:10 g:2
f:2 e:5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you could do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $i = 1;    
while (<>) {
    my %h;                            # create an empty hash every line
    foreach (split /["\s]/) {         # split on double quotes and spaces
        $h{$_}++ if /:/;              # if colon found, add element to hash
    }
    if (keys %h > 1) {                # if more than one element in hash
        print (($i++), q/. "/, (join " ", (keys %h)),  qq/"\n/);
    }
}
```

Usage: `file.pl in.txt > out.txt`

I wasn't sure what your exact criterion for including the line was but the above code works for your sample data. Because a hash is being used, the contents isn't necessarily in the right order. If you wanted to `sort` the values, that would be a minor modification.

output:

```
1. "c:10 a:1 g:2"
2. "f:2 e:5"
```

Answer (score 1):

This ugly one-liner also uses a hash but in a way that preserves the order of fields.

```
perl -ne '
  %h=(); 
  print qq($nr. "$_"\n) 
    if $_=join " ", grep !$h{$_}++, /\w+:\d+/g and / / and ++$nr
' in.txt > out.txt
```

output:

```
1. "a:1 c:10 g:2"
2. "f:2 e:5"
```